# CohFT: Witten vs. Kontsevich and Manin

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Is there any connection to CohFTs as defined [by Witten in his 1988 paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104161738) (via topological twist) and the [CohFTs as defined by Kontsevich and Manin](https://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/TEXTS/WithManinCohFT.pdf) (in the context of Gromov-Witten theory of course).

I mean, is there a general definition of CohFT such that every simple (physics or maths) example such as Donaldson theory, Vafa-Witten theory, Gromov-Witten theory, Donaldson-Thomas theory, etc falls under this definition?

Comment: Are you ok with factorisation algebras? You can translate everything to this language.

Comment: Can you please provide details?

Comment: I'm not the best person here to talk about factorisation algebras. For topological twists, you may want to look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10806.pdf . The point is that anything constructed from a BRST-BV like formalism will fit into this formalism too. But you want something less general I suppose.

Comment: Btw, I think that Witten defined Gromov-Witten cohomologically before Kontsevich-Manin in https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/1990/0001/0001/SDG-1990-0001-0001-a005.pdf

Comment: Indeed, but unlike GW theory, Donaldson theory or Vafa-Witten theory do not fall under the same CohFT definition as the GW theory. Of course they live in different dimensions. But my question remains. Is there an umbrella definition for any CohFT for any dimension?

Comment: I'm having some difficult in understanding what you call CohFT. I can't see anything in common besides the obvious.

Comment: What is the obvious? To me it is not obvious at all when a theory (in physics) is a CohFT.

Comment: The obvious is the formalism that I already mentioned, which fits pretty much any field theory from the Heisenberg point of view. I have no idea what QFT would not be a CohFT in your setting. Do you have an example in mind? Are you calling anything that gives invariants with values in the cohomology of a moduli space a CohFT?

Comment: Of course. To the best of my knowledge examples which in some cases refer to as CohFTs are not quite topological. E.g. the topologically twisted (Donaldson twist) $\mathcal{N}=2$ theory with $N_f=4$ flavors is not quite topological since the path integral (or some correlators) can develop smooth metric dependence.